# Why ViewControllers don't completely fit the screen in an iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

When I launch my app in an iPhone, the `UIViewControllers` fit the screen. But in an iPad, the result is this:

[image]

The `UIViewControllers` don't fit the screen. Why is this happening?

Comment: Is your app a Universal one or an iPhone one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats probably because use set `iPhone` as device in `deployment info` of `general` tab in `target settings`.

[image: Device settings]
iPad can open iPhone apps by default but without any modification on it's layout. then you have a button on lower right corner to zoom in.

If you want your app to support both iPad and iPhone in a native way, you should pick `universal`. **BUT BE CAREFUL!** Once you pick universal and upload it tho appstore, there is no way back to change it to single mode (iPhone/iPad only) and you shod continue supporting all platforms. The only way is to delete project entirely and create new one and it means that you may loose all of your users by loosing continues delivery.